# Crash when updating Dictionary (Heap corruption detected, free list is damaged at ...)

Tags: swift, xcode, dictionary

So I'm loading some images from files which I saved in the app's document directory and upon completion, I update a dictionary which holds all the images for my tableview. So far so good, everything's working just fine.

But now I've stumbled upon a really peculiar crash. Sometimes when updating the dictionary the app crashes, giving me the error message: "Heap corruption detected, free list is damaged at ...".

I've added a symbolic breakpoint at malloc_error_break and turned on the Address Sanitizer the Undefined Behaviour Sanitizer and Zombie Objects as advised in this post: [iOS error : Heap corruption detected, free list is damaged and Incorrect guard value: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52420160/ios-error-heap-corruption-detected-free-list-is-damaged-and-incorrect-guard-v)

Now I'm getting the following error message, which doesn't really help me either:

```
2019-06-09 17:35:20.806306+0200 Wizy[9953:3221129] -[NSIndexPath count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8000000000000000
2019-06-09 17:36:28.490834+0200 Wizy[9953:3221129] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSIndexPath count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8000000000000000'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1fc9d7ea0 0x1fbba9a40 0x1fc8f0d04 0x1fc9dd7b8 0x1fc9df45c 0x10952fbdc 0x10952fb5c 0x104868004 0x10461a178 0x104b59fd8 0x1045e4bd0 0x1067817c8 0x10a093824 0x10a094dc8 0x10a0a6330 0x10a0a6bc8 0x1fc5f417c 0x1fc5f6cec)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I have no clue as to what could've caused that crash, hopefully someone can help me out here!